# nuxt 2 <video> with require on src create error

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, video, p5.js

This one should be hard to find, chatGPT give some clues like webpack version error but no chance for now..

The error happen when I load a required file in createVideo function in a nuxt page or put it has src on a video tag
like this

```
createVideo(require('myurl'))
```

path is ok, everything is smooth only I have this error on nuxt side in the console

```
 ERROR  context.outputFileSystem.lstat is not a function

  at size (node_modules/webpack-dev-middleware/dist/middleware.js:157:36)
  at new Promise (<anonymous>)
  at processRequest (node_modules/webpack-dev-middleware/dist/middleware.js:155:28)
  at ready (node_modules/webpack-dev-middleware/dist/utils/ready.js:17:5)
  at Object.middleware (node_modules/webpack-dev-middleware/dist/middleware.js:69:5)
  at node_modules/pify/index.js:33:11
  at new Promise (<anonymous>)
  at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/pify/index.js:6:9)
  at Object.apply (node_modules/pify/index.js:80:20)
  at WebpackBundler.middleware (node_modules/@nuxt/webpack/dist/webpack.js:1863:37)
  at node_modules/@nuxt/server/dist/server.js:495:14
  at call (node_modules/connect/index.js:239:7)
  at next (node_modules/connect/index.js:183:5)
  at SendStream.error (node_modules/serve-static/index.js:121:7)
  at SendStream.emit (node:events:512:28)
  at SendStream.error (node_modules/send/index.js:270:17)
  at SendStream.onStatError (node_modules/send/index.js:417:12)
  at onstat (node_modules/send/index.js:722:26)
  at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (node:fs:191:21)
```

I Have this loader configuration in nuxt.config web pack

```
config.module.rules.push({
        test: /\.(mp4|webm|ogg)$/,
        loader: "file-loader",
        options: {
          name: "[path][name].[ext]",
          esModule: false,
        },
      })
```

and webpack5: true to match P5 version

Hope someone will understand where the error come from

Thanks in advance

edit: this happen also on a fresh installation so it should be a major problem with nuxt 2 apps and video tag

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this is a mismatch between the memory file system that is being used in `nuxt-webpack@2.16.3` and the one that is being used by `webpack-dev-middleware` at version 5.1.0 and above.

`nuxt-webpack@2.16.3` uses `memory-fs`, a deprecated package which does not include an `lstat` function (hence the error message) but `webpack-dev-middleware` requires this function as of [this commit](https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-middleware/commit/e8b21f0979c4807b28f7be45aff0d25cca1585ae).

I was able to work around the issue by resolving the `webpack-dev-middleware` version to `5.0.0`, before the call to this function was introduced. To do so, add this to your package.json

```
"overrides": {
...
"webpack-dev-middleware": "5.0.0"
}
```

It's worth mentioning that it is also possible to override the in-memory outputFileSystem that is used by the webpack-dev-middleware, and you should be able to replace `memory-fs` with `memfs`, however I was not able to get this working. Since this only affects the dev server, I decided that downgrading the `webpack-dev-middleware` package was a good enough work around for my purposes.